# Gnome Extensions Not Working

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I am currently unable to use any of my extensions. I am running Gnome 3.24, and when I tried to remove an extension, they all became disabled and now I can't re-enable them.

[image: What tweak tool looks currently like]

I've read through some of the older posts with this type of issue and didn't have any success with resolving this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweak-tool/+bug/1681918), as a workaround you can turn them back on again by click the button:

[image]

Which can be located in the `gnome-tweak-tool`'s Extension section in the top-right hand corner next to the window-control buttons (minimize, maximize and close). In fact, it can be seen in the screenshot you provide.